# A real function problem

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with continuous derivative such that $f(\sqrt{2}) = 2$ and $$f(x) = \lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)\,ds \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}.$$ Then $f(3)$ equals

$(a) \ \ \sqrt{3} \hspace{1.25 in} (b) \ \ 3\sqrt{2} \hspace{1.25 in} (c) \ \ 3\sqrt{3} \hspace{1.25 in} (d) \ \ 9$

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTN9L.jpg)

Can someone help me solve this problem on real function .
Here is my try 
I differentiated both sides with respect to $x$. And I got derivative of $x$ to be $0$.
I concluded $f(x)$ is a constant function.
So answer should be $2$. But $2$ is not an option . 
How to solve this ??

Answer (score 14):

[We have](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html):
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)\,ds\\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t}sf(s)\,\Big|_{x-t}^{x+t}-\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t}f(s)\,ds\\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t}sf(s)\,\Big|_{x-t}^{x+t}-f(x)
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
2f(x)&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t}s f(s)\,\Big|_{x-t}^{x+t}\\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t}\cdot \left[ (x+t)f(x+t) - (x-t)f(x-t) \right]\\
&=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2t}\cdot \left[ x(f(x+t) - f(x-t)) +t(f(x+t) + f(x-t)) \right]\\
&=x \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+t) - f(x-t)}{2t} + \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+t) + f(x-t)}{2}\\
&=xf'(x) + f(x)
\end{align}
Or 
$$f(x)=xf'(x)$$
[which is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx*y%27) $$f(x)=c x$$
or, from $f(\sqrt{2})=2$,
$$f(x)=\sqrt{2} x$$
the answer is **(b)**

Comment: You may more easily obtain $f(x)=x f'(x)$ by noting that $ \lim_{t\to 0}(1/t)\int_x^{x+t}sf'(s)ds=$ $\lim_{t\to 0}(1/t)\int_{x-t}^xsf'(s)ds$ $=xf'(x).$

Comment: Yep, that's a nice shortcut indeed, thank you @user254665!

Comment: What is the first step you have done

Comment: Is it a formula?

Comment: Thanks I get it you have used by parts